# How can I know what is preventing my socket to bind to localhost:50060-50959

Tags: networking, windows-10, port, tcp, sockets

I am using this Python code to listen to a port on my Windows 10 system:

```
import socket
for port in (50059, 50060, 50959, 50960):
  try:
    print(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).bind(('localhost', port)))
  except OSError as e:
    print(e)
```

However, it prints

```
None
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
None
```

meaning that I cannot access ports 50060 and 50959. I experimented further and confirmed that I cannot listen to any port in the range 50060-50959.

**Update**: After upgrading to Windows 10, 2004, it's port range 50060-59708 that is blocked somehow.

I would like to listen to port 50323, which falls into this range (in both cases).

I have tried `netstat -aonq` to find the culprit, but without success

```
C:\Users\bers>netstat -aon | grep :50
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8008 (Connected Devices Platform Service)
  TCP    10.0.0.20:50985        51.105.249.223:443     ESTABLISHED     5208 (Windows Push Notifications System Service)
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*                                    4936
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5050           *:*                                    8008
  UDP    [::]:500               *:*                                    4936
```

Nothing else seems to be listening in this range. So why can't I? `50060-50959` is exactly 900 ports - I am sure this is no coincidence. (**Update**: Well, I was - it's 9649 ports on Windows 10, 2004.)

I have checked

- [10013 No socket could be created error, however nothing is listening on that port](https://superuser.com/questions/1206630/10013-no-socket-could-be-created-error-however-nothing-is-listening-on-that-por)
- [TCP/UDP ports that cannot be bound (permission error), but don't show up in netstat](https://superuser.com/questions/556759/tcp-udp-ports-that-cannot-be-bound-permission-error-but-dont-show-up-in-nets)
- [Determining what process has bound a port (without listening) on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/557665/determining-what-process-has-bound-a-port-without-listening-on-windows)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

This means I have also tried `netstat -q`, see above, `tcpview.exe`, `resmon.exe`, and disabled Internet Connection Sharing (ICS).

Comment: For now, I can add that shutting down Workstation, WWAN Autoconfig, and WLAN Autoconfig services fixed the problem until the next reboot. Even restarting the services does not make the problem re-appear. Will do more bisecting later. This does not answer the question how to immediately identify the culprit, though.

Comment: `net stop WlanSvc & net start WlanSvc` seems to free the ports. Why?

Comment: Not all that surprisingly, this approach has stopped working after upgrading to Windows 10, 2004.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010365/how-to-see-what-is-reserving-ephemeral-port-ranges-on-windows

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217076/docker-port-bind-fails-why-a-permission-denied

Answer (score 4):

If you face this issue on Win10 2004 that's because of an issue in this update, do the [following](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171):

```
netsh int ipv[46] set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384

reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hns\State /v EnableExcludedPortRange /d 0 /f
```

I face this on opening Jetbrains IDEs and many other program that use sockets.

Comment: Great information. `netsh int ip show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` shows the port ranges in questions - they are not in use, but excluded.

Comment: In my case, only the `netsh` command was necessary (followed by a restart); so I'd recommend only running the registry-changing command if the `netsh` command is insufficient.

Comment: @Venryx the commands "net stop winnat" and then "net start winnat" should do the trick, without having to do a restart