# Can't remove port from excludedportrange

Tags: windows-10, netsh

I cannot remove port 80 from excludedportrange. Here's the complete list of exclusions (run in elevated cmd):

```
C:\Users\CptBartender>netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges

Start Port    End Port
----------    --------
        80          80
      5985        5985
      8005        8005
     47001       47001
     50000       50059     *

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

When I try to remove port 80, I get:

```
C:\Users\CptBartender>netsh int ipv4 delete excludedportrange protocol=tcp 80 1
Access denied.
```

My guess is I don't have rights to modify the relevant part of the registry.

How can I remove port 80 from the exclusion list?

Running `net stop winnat` as recommended [here](https://superuser.com/a/1610009/583409) did not help