# How do I know what element is missing when I get "Element not found" error in netsh?

Tags: networking

When I run `netsh int ipv4 delete excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=61600 numberofports=100` in Windows Command Prompt (as administrator) I get "Element not found", which I find unhelpful.

I learned this command from [Many excludedportranges how to delete - hyper-v is disabled](https://superuser.com/questions/1579346/many-excludedportranges-how-to-delete-hyper-v-is-disabled).

Wondering if someone else can shed light.

Edit: here is the output requested by @Ramhound

```
$> netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces

Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
 82           1        1199  connected     _Common_CSN_VPN_na_res - vpn.****.com
  1          75  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
  7          35        1500  connected     Wi-Fi
 25          25        1500  disconnected  Local Area Connection* 1
 12           5        1500  disconnected  Ethernet 2
 13          25        1500  disconnected  Local Area Connection* 2
  4          65        1500  disconnected  Bluetooth Network Connection
 18           1        1300  connected     Ethernet 3
 16          35        1500  disconnected  Ethernet 4
 29          15        1500  connected     vEthernet (Default Switch)
  5          25        1500  connected     VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2
  3          35        1500  connected     VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
 27          35        1500  connected     VMware Network Adapter VMnet8
 85        5000        1500  connected     vEthernet (WSL)
```